# How can I start a second Java process?

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

How can I start a second Java process platform independent? Ideally it should be the same Java version that currently running. Are there any helpful system properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible, in general.

The recipe provided in @khachik's answer will not necessarily work for a non Sun implementation of Java.

- The java executable is not necessarily called `java` and doesn't necessarily live in the `bin` subdirectory.  Even with Sun Java, on Windows there are two executables; `java` and `javaw`.
- The command options for the command that starts a JVM are different for different Java implementations.  So the `ProcessBuilder` step may involve non-portable arguments.

---

While most JVMs have adopted the primary Sun `java` command options, there are numerous differences.  For example:

- [IBM J9](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/J9) uses `j9` and `j9w` as the executable names.
- [BEA / Oracle JRockit](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/intro.html) has different `-X` and `-XX` options.
- [Jikes RVM](http://jikesrvm.org/Running+the+RVM) uses `rvm` as the executable name, and only supports a *subset* of Sun's `java` options.
- [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net) uses `ikvm` as the executable name.

(Note: these are just examples that stand out in a cursory reading of the respective online documentation.)

Comment: Any links to support your first claim?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `java.home` system property to find the current JVM:

```
String jvm = new java.io.File(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("java.home"),
                                               "bin"),
                              "java").getAbsolutePath();
```

and then run it using `ProcessBuilder` (or `Runtime.exec`).

Note that for JDK `java.home` points to the JRE directory included in JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Apache Commons libs? If you haven't give the [launcher project](http://commons.apache.org/launcher/) a try. It was quite useful for me some time ago.

Here's the project description from their site:

> The Launcher Component is designed to be a cross platform Java application launcher.
>
> The original Java classes come from the Tomcat 4.0 project.
>
> Commons-launcher eliminates the need for a batch or shell script to launch a Java class. Some situations where elimination of a batch or shell script may be desirable are:
>
> - You want to avoid having to determining where certain application paths are e.g. your application's home directory, etc. Determining this dynamically in a Windows batch scripts is very tricky on some versions of Windows or when softlinks are used on Unix platforms.
> - You want to avoid having to handle native file and path separators or native path quoting issues.
> - You need to enforce certain system properties e.g. java.endorsed.dirs when running with JDK 1.4.
> - You want to allow users to pass in custom JVM arguments or system properties without having to parse and reorder arguments in your script. This can be tricky and/or messy in batch and shell scripts.
>     You want to bootstrap system properties from a configuration file instead hard-coding them in your batch and shell scripts.
> - You want to provide localized error messages which is very tricky to do in batch and shell scripts.

Comment: If I understand it then it does not help to start a Java process else any external process where I know the executable. But this is the problem. I does not know the current executable.