# How can I start a 'main' in a new process in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, program-entry-point

The question is rather simple. How can I start a main method in another java process? Now I do it like this:

```
startOptions = new String[] {"java", "-jar", "serverstart.jar"};
new ProcessBuilder(startOptions).start();
```

But they asked me to do it not with an external .jar file. The serverstart.jar obviously has a main method, but it it possible to call that main method in another process, without calling the .jar file?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
new ProcessBuilder(ServerStart.main(startOptions)).start();
```

But I don't know if anything like that exists.

Comment: Would it help, or be permitted, to duplicate current classpath as an argument in your ProcessBuilder? .. System.getProperty("java.class.path")

Comment: I don't know, how do I have to do it then?

Comment: then you will have classpath with you you just need to pass it to `-cp` and load `java`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming a new thread with a new classloader is not enough (I would vote for this solution though), I understand you need to create a distinct process that invokes a main method in a class without having that declared as "jar main method" in the manifest file -- since you don't have a distinct serverstart.jar anymore.

In this case, you can simply call `java -cp $yourClassPath your.package.ServerStart`, as you would do for running any java application when you don't have (or don't want to use) the manifest Main-Class.

Comment: I did it like his: `startOptions = new String[] {"java", "-cp", System.getProperty("user.dir"), "target.classes." + ServerStart.class.getName()};` But it gives me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: target/classes/sample/plugin/hello_maven_plugin/
ServerStart (wrong name: sample/plugin/hello_maven_plugin/ServerStart)` So I guess I'm in the right directory, bu he can't find the right class I guess.

Comment: Assuming your `user.dir` is the maven project root directory, `target/classes` should NOT be used as package prefix, but instead added to the file system path: `new String[] {"java", "-cp",  System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/classes", ServerStart.class.getName()}`

Comment: Nice! I'm in the right class now, but now I have the problem that he can't find a specified .jar file. In my ServerStart, he starts a server imported from hsqldb, but he can't find it. `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.Server`

Comment: However, it's not a good idea to rely on running the application from the maven project root dir, so I think a better solution would be to simply reuse the classpath of the current process (and use the current directory as fall-back): `new String[] {"java", "-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path", "."), ServerStart.class.getName()}`

Comment: I wrote my previous comment before I saw your reply, but it seems to address this latest issue that you mentioned also, as the FULL classpath of the current process will be used.

Comment: Another error: ´java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sample/plugin/hello_maven_plugin/ServerStart Caused by: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.plugin.hello_maven_plugin.ServerStart´

Comment: Can you debug the result of the `System.getProperty("java.class.path", ".")` call ? And also, are you running the application within some IDE ?

Comment: The `System.getProperty("java.class.path", ".")` refers to apache-maven-2.2.1\boot\classworlds-1.1.jar. I'm writing a maven plugin to start, stop and clean a database. I'm using cmd to call the plugin.

Comment: And... does that classworlds-1.1.jar contain the class you're trying to use as main (`sample.plugin.hello_maven_plugin.ServerStart`) ?

Comment: I got the problem fixed, but now there is another problem. I use a loop to keep the server alive, when I run the command, my cmd is trapped in that loop. If I run the code with the -jar options as I did in my first post, the cmd is not trapped in the loop, so I still can use it. So this method is actually not doing what I want it to do.

Comment: Got it! He was also trapped in another loop, to show us the errors. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Creating a new "java" process from java is *not* possible since *two processes can't share one JVM*. (See this [question and the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421658/how-can-i-start-a-second-java-process)).

---

If you can live with creating a new `Thread` instead of a `Process` you can do it with a custom `ClassLoader`. It is as **close you can get to a new process**. All static and final fields will be reinitialized!

Also note that the `"ServerStart` class (for the example below) must be in the class path of the current executing JVM):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // start the server
    start("ServerStart", "arg1", "arg2");
}

private static void start(final String classToStart, final String... args) {

    // start a new thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                // create the custom class loader
                ClassLoader cl = new CustomClassLoader();

                // load the class
                Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass(classToStart);

                // get the main method
                Method main = clazz.getMethod("main", args.getClass());

                // and invoke it
                main.invoke(null, (Object) args);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And this is the custom class loader:

```
private static class CustomClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    public CustomClassLoader() {
        super(new URL[0]);
    }

    protected java.lang.Class<?> findClass(String name) 
    throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try{
            String c = name.replace('.', File.separatorChar) +".class";
            URL u = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(c);
            String classPath = ((String) u.getFile()).substring(1);
            File f = new File(classPath);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

            byte buff[] = new byte[(int) f.length()];
            dis.readFully(buff);
            dis.close();

            return defineClass(name, buff, 0, buff.length, (CodeSource) null);

        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Creating a new "java" process from java is not possible since two processes can't share one JVM.` -- maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see sharing one JVM as a requirement here.

Comment: @Costi, No, but ServerStart.main(startOptions) indicates that there is is a posibility that he would like to call the main-method from within the JVM.

Comment: Sure, but that's simply a method call, it has nothing to do with any new process.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off subclassing URLClassLoader rather than ClassLoader? Then you'd be able to handle Jars and class directories without any effort.

Comment: @aioobe: I got it now, the `ProcessBuilder` in conjuction with a `main()` method call does indeed create this confusion, so dacwe was right to clarify this from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest invoking a shellscript from java and using it to start the new process (if you cant live with just another thread at all).

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer here how to create multi process application without spring :).
With spring you can do this by xml config. 
*Multithread is another story, this is multi-process*

Create a JavaProces class as seen below. You can store a counterparter XML/JSON of this class in your environment. Then start your process with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(processRunnerString);`,

You should first find `java.exe` , `vm args`, then set `-classpath` then `mainClass` and `args` respectively.

> Finally you will have something like java JRE\java.exe -classpath
>   .;*;lib* AClass arg1 - Dprop=val

You can use `JMX` to communicate with other process.

```
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.List;

public class JavaProcess {

    private String mainClass;
    private Dictionary<String, String> vmParameters;
    private List<String> classPath;
    private List<String> mainArgs;

    public String getMainClass() {
        return mainClass;
    }

    public void setMainClass(String mainClass) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
    }

    public Dictionary<String, String> getVmParameters() {
        return vmParameters;
    }

    public void setVmParameters(Dictionary<String, String> vmParameters) {
        this.vmParameters = vmParameters;
    }

    public List<String> getClassPath() {
        return classPath;
    }

    public void setClassPath(List<String> classPath) {
        this.classPath = classPath;
    }

    public List<String> getMainArgs() {
        return mainArgs;
    }

    public void setMainArgs(List<String> mainArgs) {
        this.mainArgs = mainArgs;
    }

}
```

> MainRunner Application, you can gather JavaProcess instance from a
>   configuration file. I just created a dummy Process here and in case of
>   error I stop it from callback of the process.

```
    //process
    JavaProcess jp = new JavaProcess();

    //java class
    jp.setMainClass("com.hmg.vidapter.run.DriverLauncher");

    //main args[]
    List<String> mainArgsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mainArgsList.add("ABC1 ARG2 ARG3 ARGN");
    jp.setMainArgs(mainArgsList);

    //-classpath
    List<String> classPath = new ArrayList<String>();
    classPath.add("*");
    classPath.add("libs\\*");
    classPath.add("repo\\*");
    jp.setClassPath(classPath);

    //-Dvm args.
    Dictionary<String, String> vmArgs = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    vmArgs.put("-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", "");
    vmArgs.put("-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", "");
    vmArgs.put("-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1453", "");
    vmArgs.put("-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false", "");
    jp.setVmParameters(vmArgs);

    String params = JSONUtils.convertToJSON(jp);
    System.out.println(params);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\"" + getJavaExecutablePath()+ "\"");

    sb.append(" ");

    Enumeration<String> vmaEnum = vmArgs.keys();
    while (vmaEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = vmaEnum.nextElement();
        sb.append(key + " ");
        String val=vmArgs.get(key);
        if(val!=null && !val.isEmpty())
        {
            sb.append(val + " ");
        }
    }

    sb.append(" -classpath ");
    List<String> cps = jp.getClassPath();
    for (String cp : cps) {
        sb.append(cp+";");
    }
    sb.append(" ");             
    sb.append(jp.getMainClass());
    sb.append(" ");

    List<String> mainArgs = jp.getMainArgs();
    for (String ma : mainArgs) {
        sb.append(ma+" ");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sb.toString());

    //write output
    InputStreamReader isrO = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader brO = new BufferedReader(isrO);
    String callBackO = brO.readLine();
    if (callBackO!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Application Output: " + callBackO);         
    }

    //write errput
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String callBack = br.readLine();
    if (callBack!=null)
    {
        System.err.println("Application Error: "+ callBack);
        //you can do whatever you want if you don't wanna stop it
        p.destroyForcibly();
    }
```

Determine location of java.exe from java.home env. variable

```
private static String getJavaExecutablePath(){
        String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
        File f = new File(javaHome);
        f = new File(f, "bin");
        f = new File(f, "java.exe");
        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using Reflection (java.lang.reflect package).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class c = Class.forName("ServerStart");
    Class[] argTypes = { args.getClass() };
    Method m = c.getMethod("main", argTypes);
    Object passedArgv[] = { args };
    m.invoke(null, passedArgv);
}
```

Comment: This will not start a new process and might not reinitialize static and final variables.

Comment: won't work. You need a custom `ClassLoader` to reinitialize all variables.