# How do I call main method of one class inside another class?

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

I have a thread that, when  the current application closes, must start the `main()` method of another class.
I included `ClassName.main(someStringArray)` in the `run()` of the thread but the method wasn't called. What might have gone wrong?
**The Thread I defined**:

```
private class VideoCreator extends Thread{
        public VideoCreator(){
            pathToPass = savePath + "/" + "video.mov";
            passVect.add("-w");
            passVect.add("1280");
            passVect.add("-h");
            passVect.add("800");
            passVect.add("-f");
            passVect.add("25");
            passVect.add("-o");
            passVect.add(pathToPass);
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                jpegFiles = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(pathToPass).getParent(),"*.jpg");
                for(Path jpegFile : jpegFiles){
                    passVect.add(jpegFile.toString());
                }
            }catch(IOException e){

            }
            try{
                JpegImagesToMovie.main((String[])passVect.toArray());
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Dammit Error!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void cleanUp(){

        }
        String pathToPass;
        Vector<String> passVect = new Vector<>(100,200);
        DirectoryStream<Path> jpegFiles;
    }
```

Comment: Was there some kind of exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989145/how-can-i-start-a-main-in-a-new-process-in-java

Comment: @MvG Class cast Exception. I tried to convert an array returned from `java.util.Vector` class' `toArray` to a `String[]`. The Vector is `Vector<String>`

Comment: @ErhanBagdemir, the referenced question is about starting the other application in a separate *process*, not a new *thread* of the same process.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @MvG to add clarity, I am calling the main method of [this code](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8AE9208DC5FB846910DFD3F935D64E7C9A5BB784.aspx)

Comment: Most generic comtainers in Java aren't type-checked at runtime. So even a `Vector<String>` might contain values which are not strings. You might be able to detect possibly problematic conversions by enabling the `-Xlint:unchecked` switch to `javac`, but they might be hidden inside some third-party libraries as well. I suggest you iterate over the `Vector` and print the `getClass().getName()` of every item, to see what you've got there.

Comment: @MvG I just posted the code so see it as it might help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
(String[])passVect.toArray()
```

you should write

```
passVect.toArray(new String[passVect.size()])
```

or (shorter but less performant)

```
passVect.toArray(new String[0])
```

The reason is that [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29) will always return an `Object[]` array, which you cannot convert to a `String[]` array even if all its members are strings. (The reverse, by the way, is possible: you can pass a `String[]` in places expecting `Object[]`, which is used by various methods of the [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class. In fact, the thing returned from the `toArray()` method *might* have been a `String[]`, even if in a standards-compliant implementation it is not. This is the reason why the compiler didn't complain: it doesn't know or care about the internals of the method, and judging from the return type, an explicit cast to an array of a subclass might be possible if the array was created as such.)

The [`toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) call returns an array of the required type, if you pass an array of that type as an argument. If the passed argument has the correct length, it will be used directly; otherwise a new array will be allocated. For this reason, allocating the correct length in the first place will avoid one allocation along the way.

Comment: Wait, I guess it is the `Path` being added that is causing the problem. Can you rectify that? The `toString()` for `Path` returns nothin as I tried printing it using `System.out.println()` and got nothing on the screen

Comment: Sir, I believe it is the `DirectoryStream<>` causing the problem.

Comment: @DummyDerp: The above fix should avoid the class cast exception encountered when turning the Vector into an array. There might be other errors before or after that, and you might learn more by not ignoring exceptions the way your first catch block does. But as these appear to be independent issues, I suggest you have a look at the next exception, try to fix that yourself, and ask a new and detailed question including code and exception if that fails.

Comment: The error was because passPath was getting a null value assigned to it. I fixed it. Will let you know the outcome in a few minutes

Comment: here is another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412938/directorystreampath-lists-files-in-a-haphazard-manner